# Sourcetree git executable on windows path

Tags: git, intellij-idea, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using sourcetree on windows as my git client, and did not manually install git. When i open Intellij i get an error saying git client cannot be found and an option to configure the path git executable.

I've tried locating it in sourcetree directory and in user directories but was not able to find it.

Can someone point me to it's path?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found it!

%USER_DIR%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\git.exe

Comment: You can always find it in menu Tools > Options > Git, scroll at the bottom, Git Version section